# Two different url details in a single API in wso2 MI

Tags: java, xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

URL 1 -Inventory details(inventory.inventoryapi)
URL 2 -Product details(product.productapi)

From inventory details API we need to get productId and inventory details of that product using inventoryId after getting this result ,using the productId it will show the product details in a single API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Service Orchestration](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/integration-use-case/service-orchestration-overview/#service-orchestration) using WSO2 Micro Integrator. Previous link also provides an official step-by-step example.